# How can I use a docker container with a self signed certificate on osx?

Tags: php, macos, ssl, docker, self-signed

I'm using Docker to test within an Apache/PHP environment (https://github.com/tutumcloud/apache-php).

The scripts that i'm using require that I be on a secure connection (https). This can even be a self signed certificate. Anything to get the browser to work over https. The problem is that docker only seems to work over http.

**How can I get docker to run with a self signed cert over https?**

Previously i've used a different NPM module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to use http-server and used a self signed cert which works great to get on HTTPS, unfortunately it only serves static files and nothing server side like PHP.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want docker api to work on https? Please clarify.

Comment: When I use my localhost to access my docker container ( my php pages on an apache server ) I would like to be able to access it with https ( which does not work currently ) instead of http.

Comment: Would your provide the information `how do you launch the docker container? e.g. docker run` and `how do you access your service running in a container? what address are you using?`? Please provide some scripts or code you are using.

Comment: I think @sjmartin would like run this docker container with apache, open https://localhost and get correct page, rendered by apache from this container. Am I right?

Comment: @AlexanderEmelianov - yes that is correct, via https in the URL bar.

Comment: So is this question really "how do I configure Apache to serve HTTPS pages?"

Comment: @miken32 Technically, perhaps in the backend, but I was looking for what AlexanderEmelianov had answered below. A baked-in solution with SSL available out of the box with apache/php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker image that you use does not provide SSL by default. You can upgrade it and create your own image based on it with added SSL. But it is job for DevOps. So, you can easily use another docker image from docker hub which supports SSL out of the box.

Only try https://hub.docker.com/r/eboraas/apache-php/ - it supports SSH and PHP

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I have tested and SSL works out of the box!